# Accept-Encoding how to find is file is actually compressed

Tags: asp.net, http, iis-7

I am a little confused about `Accept-Encoding`. I have Web Service which would accept compressed file submission using POST method. I have added code below which look for `Accept-Encoding: gzip` and decompress submitted file. The problem is with a files which are submitted from internet browsers. Request headers contain gzip but file is not actually compressed. Maybe someone could help to understand how to detect is file actually compressed?

```
var httpPostedFile = httpRequest.Files[0];
var contentLength = httpPostedFile.ContentLength;
var buffer = new byte[contentLength];
httpPostedFile.InputStream.Read(buffer, 0, contentLength);

const string acceptEncoding = "Accept-Encoding";
if (httpRequest.Headers[acceptEncoding] != null && httpRequest.Headers[acceptEncoding].Contains("gzip"))
{

  buffer = Decompress(buffer);
}

 static byte[] Decompress(byte[] gzip)
        {            
            using (var stream = new GZipStream(new MemoryStream(gzip), CompressionMode.Decompress))
            {
                const int size = 4096;
                var buffer = new byte[size];
                using (var memory = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    int count;
                    do
                    {
                        count = stream.Read(buffer, 0, size);
                        if (count > 0)
                        {
                            memory.Write(buffer, 0, count);
                        }
                    }
                    while (count > 0);
                    return memory.ToArray();
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Accept-Encoding indicates what encodings the client *accepts*.

The encoding of a given request is specified using Transfer-Encoding and Content-Encoding, but note that these will always apply to the whole request body, not just part of a multipart payload.